# Test language switching on Codeship

Tags: django, internationalization, codeship

I'm doing a basic test to ensure once the language is switched, the right text is loaded.  Locally, the test works but the same test fails on codeship.

The code:

```
class LanguageTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        translation.activate("sw")

    def tearDown(self):
        translation.activate("en")

    def test_menu_options_sw(self):
        for s in TOP_LEVEL_MENUS:
            self.assertRegexpMatches(response.text, s)
```

The variable `TOP_LEVEL_MENUS` is just a list of options the user should see in the other language which is activated in `setUp` Currently on codeship, the language still remains the default ie English and not Swahili (sw).

Any ideas why the test fails on Codeship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an extra step in the codeship script to compile the po file resolved everything

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy,

could you send us an in app support request (or an email to support@codeship.com) including a link the the failing build, so we can take a look at the build log and the error message?

Best, 
Marko

[Disclaimer] I'm working for Codeship (obviously)

Comment: Ahoy...actually I found out I was missing the compiled translation file on codeship hence the fail!  A very d'oh! moment indeed

Comment: Ok, great it's working now. Let us know if you have any other questions!